# Finding errors in this step of mysql installation in ubuntu 14.04 "sudo mysql_install_db "

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu-14.04

Installing MySQL system tables...
150623 11:01:43 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) 
starting as process 24482 ...

OK
Filling help tables...
150623 11:01:43 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.43-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) starting as process 24488 ...

OK

To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy
support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system

PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !

To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:

/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h praveen password 'new-password'

Alternatively you can run:
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

which will also give you the option of removing the test
databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
strongly recommended for production servers.

See the manual for more instructions.

You can start the MySQL daemon with:
cd /usr ; /usr/bin/mysqld_safe &

You can test the MySQL daemon with mysql-test-run.pl
cd /usr/mysql-test ; perl mysql-test-run.pl

Please report any problems at http://bugs.mysql.com/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link to install phpmyadmin

[phpMyAdmin Installation](http://devoncmather.com/setting-aws-ec2-instance-lamp-git/#installLamp)